# displaying 2 product per row on phone and 4 product per row on desktop using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a static e-commerce website using bootstrap. I want 2 product in a row while it opens in the phone and 4 product in a row while open in desktop or i-pad.

```
<div class="container">

 <div class="row product">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="image">
            <a href="products.php?q=10020" target="_blank"><img id="10030" src="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="image">
            <a href="products.php?q=10020" target="_blank"><img id="10030" src="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="image">
            <a href="products.php?q=10020" target="_blank"><img id="10030" src="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="image">
            <a href="products.php?q=10020" target="_blank"><img id="10030" src="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

There is more than 1 row on this page. 
please help me to solve this.

Comment: Read the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/) for how to use the `col` classes.

Comment: This is exactly what the Boostrap grid system was built for: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: Read the use of `-lg- `, `-md-`, `-sm-` etc and hopefully you can find your answer. There is also a demo in W3school see it.

Comment: I know this is a bootstrap grid system. But I can use 4 col-sm-6 under a single row.

Comment: Yes, use `col-sm-6 col-md-3`. It's fine to have [more than 12 column units in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679160/bootstrap-3-more-than-12-columns-in-a-row).

Answer (score 0):

the issue that you are having is because of your bootstrap grid.

I made an example below.  Pay attention to: class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"

Here are the docs.  https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="background-color:green;">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="background-color:red;">3</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="background-color:yellow;">4</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```